# No memory loss inside a class

Tags: c++

I've got this code:

```
class MyClass{
public:
    string myString;
    MyClass(char *aString){
        this->myString = std::string(aString);
    }
}

int main(){
    MyClass example = MyClass("Hi!");
    printf("%s\n", example.myString.c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

Testing this with valgrind shows no problems, but I can't understand why I can avoid using new to create the string copy.

After the constructor execution ends shouldn't "this.myString" be lost in the stack?

Shouldn't I ask for that memory? Why?

Edit:
I believe I'm getting confused because doing what I would consider "equivalent" in C, would cause errors when tested with valgrind:

```
typedef struct MyStruct{
    char *p;
}MyStruct_t;

void createMyStruct(MyStruct_t *aStruct, char *text){
    char str[10];
    strcpy(str,text);
    aStruct->p = str;
}

int main(){
    MyStruct_t example;
    createMyStruct(&example, "Hi!");
    printf("%s\n", example.p);
    return 0;
}
```

What am I getting wrong?

Comment: A small point of interest is that `string` can in theory keep its data (the characters) wherever it wants.

Comment: You shall understand and distinguish the difference of static and dynamic allocation.

Comment: @cbel I believe i do, that's the reason why I do not understand why a variable which I consider is static, can be accessed after the constructor execution ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your **Edit**, which is actually a completely separate question to the original.

In this code:

```
void createMyStruct(MyStruct_t aStruct, char *text);

MyStruct_t example;
createMyStruct(example, "Hi!");
```

You pass `example` **by value** to `createMyStruct`. The `example` is copied (which has bogus semantics because you have not properly defined a copy-constructor etc. for `MyStruct_t`) and the changes in that function have no effect on `example`.

Let's say that instead you decided to pass by reference:

```
void createMyStruct(MyStruct_t &aStruct, char *text){
   char str[10];
   strcpy(str,text);
   aStruct->p = str;
}
```

In this code, `str` is a local char array in `createMyStruct`. It no longer exists once `createMyStruct` ends.

After this function exits, `aStruct->p` (i.e. `example.p`) is a wild pointer.

Nothing like this is happening in the `string` case, not even close.

If you wrote `char *str = malloc(10);` instead of `char str[10];` it would be slightly more resembling the original example.

The `std::string` class manages the storage of the string data. It doesn't point at some external char array.

Comment: Yes, I corrected that now.
What I would have done in C is, as you mentioned, call malloc(), and afterwards, I would free() that memory.
I expected to have to do the same in C++ (but maybe with new/delete), but I might be missing something on how this works on c++. I'll try to get more into it and probably come back with new questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is an error:

```
this.myString = std::string(aString);
```

It should be `this->myString`.  (I have heard there is a compiler that implements using `.` on pointers as an extension... uggh)

Anyway, the effects of this line are:

1. Create a temporary object of type `std::string`, initialized by passing `aString` to its constructor. That constructor copies from your `char *` into memory which the `std::string` constructor allocates within the temporary object. A `std::string` object internally contains a pointer to some allocated storage; it doesn't refer to your string literal any more after this step.
2. Call `this->myString::operator=(std::string const &)`, where the temporary object binds to the const reference. The `std::string::operator=` function increases the memory allocation in the target string, and copies bytes over from the source string. (It doesn't "share" the allocation or anything).
3. Destruct the temporary object (and `std::string`'s destructor deletes the pointer to its storage for the string contents).

The end result is that the string contents get copied by value into `myString` , there are no memory leaks. After Step 2, there are briefly two copies in memory of the string contents.

Note that the compiler may optimize all stages of this process, so if you inspect your generated assembly it may look different. But conceptually, this is the defined list of steps.

I guess you might be coming from Java... if so, C++ has *automatic allocation* for all data types (whereas Java only has it for primitive types). You can go `T(args)` anywhere you like, and create a temporary T which lives until the end of the full-expression in which it was created.

Comment: I guess he is from Java, too.

Comment: Yes, it is this->myString, I copied it incorrectly (I was also translating the code to english).
The thing I don't understand is why the temporary object is still reachable after the constructor execution ended.
I did learn have not so long ago, but I've got some prior experience in C.
I edited my question with a C example of what I consider equivalent which fails when tested w/ valgrind.

Comment: The temporary object does not exist after the constructor ends. Your `printf` prints the member variable `myString`, which is not temporary.

Comment: But were did myString memory come from?

Comment: When you write `MyClass example;` it creates an object called `example`.  `example` has a member variable `myString`, it is part of `example`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should understand `this` keyword in C++.

> The keyword this identifies a special type of pointer. Suppose that
>   you create an object named x of class A, and class A has a nonstatic
>   member function f(). If you call the function x.f(), the keyword this
>   in the body of f() stores the address of x. You cannot declare the
>   this pointer or make assignments to it.

So you should use

```
MyClass(char *aString)
{
   this->myString = std::string(aString); // there is no need to use this
}
```